# Inequality Concerning Volumes

Tags: differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry, convex-geometry

I wanted to ask if the following holds for every convex centered body $K$ (in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$):

$\int_{S^{n-1}}|K\cap{\theta^{\perp}|}d\theta\geq|K|$

where $|K|$ is the $n$ volume of K and $|K\cap{\theta^{\perp}}|$ is the $n-1$ volume of $K\cap{\theta^{\perp}}$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The claim is wrong. One can convince himself that the euclidian ball is a counter example when $n$ is large.